# How can I prevent a blogspot blog from misusing our company's toll free number?

Tags: blog, legal, spam-prevention

An unknown blogger is utilizing the toll free  number of my company, which is leading to tons of misleading calls.

I tried contact the blogger but couldn't find any lead. I even tried asking Google to do so but Google denied and asked submit a legal notice. Is there any other means to take down the blog or contact the blogger?

Comment: Why don't you submit a legal notice which is suggested by Google?

Comment: Is this a blogger on Google's blogger.com, or is it using a different blog service?

Comment: Yes Stephen, it's a blogspot blog, [check first edit](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/108451/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can [try this Blogger form](https://support.google.com/blogger/contact/private_info) to [report inappropriate blogger](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/76315?hl=en) content

On that form, select the `Unlisted phone number` option and fill up all details.

I think Google don't consider toll free number as copyright content(DMCA), and hence you need to contact the host provider or owner. If nothing works then send legal notice to blogger and they will shutdown the post.